# Shadow problems with point light radius

Tags: error

When I increase the point light radius, it ends up creating artifacts on the textures for seemingly no reason.

[image]

Even though I I have High Quality Shadows (High bit-depth and cube map resolution).

[image]

I want to create a smooth texture just like the corner of the photo, but for some reason it ends up creating these squares with what looks like many "vertices".

Comment: Please write in english, use an online translator.

Answer (score 4):

Those are Shadow Terminator artifacts. The most common way to deal with them is adding more geometry, usually with a subdivision surface modifier.

[image]

But starting with blender 2.9 you can control the Shadow terminator aritfacts directly in the Object Properties. In the Shading section use the slider for Shadow Terminator Offset:

[image]

Comment: eu uso o eevee e meu modelo ja esta com essa modificação

Comment: @MeguiTaA12 this site works in english.