# Why does cycles render shows faceting in shadows?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm new to Blender, and I'm doing a very simple render using Cycles.  As you can see in the image, I'm getting horrible faceting in the shadows on the sphere.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210817/shadow-problems-with-point-light-radius/210895#210895

Comment: I posted a solution to this problem on yet another question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190050/66773

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the polycount of the ball, try subdividing it, either by right click in edit mode and subdivide, or using the subdivision surface modifier

Comment: As it stands your answer could use a few more details.  Could you expound why increasing the polycount is helpful or give a simple explanation of how to do the things you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

This was a major problem until Blender 2.90. There is now a feature just to solve this problem. In the "Object Properties" panel, under "Shading", turn up the "Shadow terminator" to cut out the face sets showing.
Here's a GIF of how to do it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsKKk.jpg

Comment: Yes, adjusting shadow terminator offset does fix the issue.  And I see that the option only appears when using Cycles.  But what a PITA to have to set that on an object by object  basis.  Would be nice if Cycles had a global value to fix the whole scene.  Or better yet, fix Cycles to eliminate the problem entirely.  I've never seen an issue like this in any other 3D application.